# When to link and when not to link a SO question on meta?

Tags: discussion, questions, meta

Suppose I have a question about a particular question on Stack Overflow, perhaps on why a question was edited/on-hold/closed/deleted/... Commonly on SO (but not always) users will vote and moderate in a logical and non-personal manner, although this is not the case in Meta Stack Overflow, as people seem to be more opinionated.

On Meta getting a large number of down-votes isn't a big deal since it does not affect your reputation. Although it can affect the linked question, such that it seems people whom vote you down may go to the question to vote that down as well (or vote to close/delete it). Such that valid questions can be massively down-voted (or less quality ones are voted down more than they should) and then closed or deleted.

So what would you recommend when there is a question on a post on SO, how would you go about linking a question if you are worried it will be down-voted or closed quickly?

Maybe it's rare, but some people can be rude and/or misuse moderation privileges.

Courtesy of Cupcake, here's the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185761/how-to-use-getsubmit-function-in-javascript)

[image]

Comment: It's neither rude nor misuse. People will vote on a linked question just like they would on any other question. It's just that linked questions get more attention drawn to them than usual, so naturally more people will vote on it than usual.

Comment: @Cupcake In my case it was clearly misuse. Just because this is SO doesn't mean it doesn't happen, things are never perfect no matter how much we try to make them that way.

Comment: If you truly think there was misuse, post a question about it on Meta, and/or flag the question for moderator attention, and explain that you think there is abuse going on.

Comment: @Cupcake That's exactly what I did, and it was the cause of the misuse. I can't flag the question since it's now deleted.

Comment: Did you delete your other Meta question? If you undelete it, I can go take a look. There's rarely any point to deleting a Meta question, since it doesn't affect reputation.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek We have only your assertion that the question about which you were asking was abused. It's likely that it wasn't but without the original question everything is hypothetical.

Comment: @Cupcake I can, I deleted it since people started to go to the question and down voted it, to protect the user from unnecessary reputation lost. I assumed I was wrong because people told me it was clearly too broad.

Comment: [The question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24185761/456814) in question...

Comment: @cupcake I've added a screen shot of the original question. Having done so I don't see the problem the OP here is worried about - the question is clearly too broad.

Comment: @MikeW Although there are answers in which the user wanted and accepted, the user got the answer they were looking for, all before it was on-hold. In what way is it too broad?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't control how people vote, and there isn't any way to link it that will influence that behavior one way or the other.  Nor can you ask a question about a specific SO question without linking it (since any such discussion without a link would be hypothetical).

While we try not to single-out individuals here on Meta, sometimes it is just unavoidable.  In most cases, unless you can sufficiently specify your question without a link, or provide a hypothetical example, linking the question is inevitable.

Comment: If you link, then the SO post will get "meta'ed". If you don't link, the meta post about the SO post will get "meta'ed" for not providing examples. It's great. :)

Comment: @Mysticial I see, it's just my first question on meta had a link. My question was massively down voted and the question was deleted when it should not of been, many commented for the sake of being rude. I don't know if that's common or not.

Comment: Why do you think the link had anything to do with that?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek why do you think that your question shouldn't have been deleted? Which question are you referring to?

Comment: In general, the meta-effect just means a massive influx of interested users who actively and consciously moderate the site. That means iff anything should be done on any linked questions / answers, it will be done, and fast. That counts for voting just like everything else, and irrespective of your wishes. BTW: Questions can also be "Lounge"d, which is the same mechanics, though involving the [C++ Lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well the question was only massively down voted and closed after I posted my question on the meta. In which the question was there for weeks and was inactive. Cupcake The question was labeled too-broad when it was not, it was already answered and the OP accepted and said it was exactly what they needed. I can't see the question since it's now deleted.

Answer (score 1):

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24185761/456814) that the original poster is referring to:

> I am trying to figure out how to complete the Javascript function
>   checkSubmit() so that the form cannot be submitted without a username
>   having been specified. I need an alert window to be displayed if no
>   username is entered. Also, any ideas as to how I can rewrite the
>   function so that it does not require a parameter? This is my script:
>
> ```html
>      <SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">
>      < ! --
>           function checkSubmit(value) {
>            ........
>           }
>      </SCRIPT>
>
>       <NOSCRIPT>
>           Sorry, no scripting support.
>       </NOSCRIPT>
>
>       <FORM Name = "UserForm"
>            onSubmit = "return checkSubmit(username.value)">
>
>          <P/> Please enter your username:
>             <INPUT TYPE = "text"  NAME = "username"  SIZE = "25"  VALUE = "">
>
>                <INPUT TYPE = "submit"  VALUE = "Click to submit">
>       </FORM>
> ```

Let's break this down. The user is asking for the following things:

1. "How to complete the Javascript function `checkSubmit()` so that the form cannot be submitted without a username having been specified. I need an alert window to be displayed if no username is entered."

   ```javascript
    function checkSubmit(value) {
      ........
    }
   ```

   ```html
    <FORM Name = "UserForm"
      onSubmit = "return checkSubmit(username.value)">
   ```
2. Also, any ideas as to how I can rewrite the function so that it does not require a parameter?

**The user is asking for too many things in this one question.** First, the user is essentially asking people to write his `checkSubmit` function for him, and that is very open-ended.

Second, the user also asks people how to rewrite the function so that it doesn't require a parameter, which is again an open-ended question.

It could be made less open-ended if the user had attempted to at least try to solve the problem himself. If he got stuck, he could provide the code that he tried to use, which other users could then help fix and improve.

### Verdict

Given the above, **I think it's quite justified that the question was closed as "Too broad".** It's also now 6 days old at the time of deletion. It's usually suggested on Meta that questions older than 2 days are eligible for deletion. The user had plenty of time to attempt to improve his question so that it could be re-opened, but he didn't.

Thus, **I see the deletion as justified as well**, because the question probably won't be useful to future users. If there are any users who disagree with that, they may vote to undelete the question, as long as they have at least 10k reputation.

Comment: You can state that the user wants the function `sayHello(value){ ... }` to be written to alert `Hello World` without the parameter. You can say the user wants to the answer-er to write the function for them and is therefore open-ended. But it's clear the answer is: `sayHello(){ alert("Hello World"); }`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek when you have at least 10k rep, you may vote to undelete the question. For closed questions, you may vote to reopen them when you have 3000 reputation.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Stack Overflow optimizes for high-quality, useful questions. This user's particular question is neither high-quality nor very useful to future users. You won't find many people who will miss it. Spend your time on the high-quality useful things, not the low-quality stuff that will only help the one user who asked the question.

Comment: I guess I like helping everybody `:P`

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek some people just need to learn how to fish `:P` I learned how to program before Stack Overflow even existed. Online documentation is everywhere, not to mention **tons** of blogs, and nowadays browsers have debuggers built right in!